# Get the dropdown list value into mvc controller to View thru Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

as new in MVC, I am trying to get the dropdown list value into mvc controller thru Ajax call here is the Views code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {

    $('#myForm').submit(function () {
        var select = $("#SeTime option:selected").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: {'selectedtTime' : select},
            success: function(result) {
                alert("Selected value: " + select);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>

<div >
@using (Html.BeginForm("Details", "Employee", FormMethod.Get, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id="myForm"}))
{
    @Html.DropDownList("SeTime", new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem{ Text="1 Min", Value = "60" },
        new SelectListItem{ Text="2 Min", Value = "120" },
        new SelectListItem{ Text="3 Min", Value = "180" },
    }, "Select Time")
    <input type="submit" value="Set Time "  />
}
</div>

<p>@Model.SetTime</p> //to show the selected value thru controller to view
```

Here is Model:
        public class Time
    {
        public string SetTime { get; set; }
    }

Here is the controller:

```
public ActionResult Details(string selectedtTime)
    {
        Time time = new Time();
        if (selectedtTime == null)
        {
            time.SetTime = "Hello";
        }
        else
        {
            time.SetTime = selectedtTime;
        }   
        return View(time);
    }
}
```

I am getting the right value in alert box but not in the controller (getting 'Hello' for each selection). I have also tried with POST method but didn't work. May I get some advice how to get the selected dropdown value thru controller

Comment: I suspect it's because you have the dropdownlist and corresponding jQuery spelt as `SeTime` instead of `SetTime`.

Comment: Your code looks fine. It should work fine. Can you see the network tab and see the value is passed in querystring ?

Comment: Here is a working dot net fiddle using your code from the question :) https://dotnetfiddle.net/bh4Lid

Comment: @Zahir Can you please let me know if you found a solution?

Comment: @Zahir did you solve the problem

Comment: Thanks, everyone for valuable suggestion, it is working now!

Comment: What was the fix @Zahir?

Comment: @sleeyuen, basically I got the idea from the comment of Shyju, I checked it in network tab and found that the value is not passing due to json parsing problem i.e. problem was with jQuery reference.

Comment: @Zahir did you check last updated version of my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44663048/8175473 and last .Netfiddle link

Comment: @user8175473 Sorry for late reply, yes I got it, and thank u very much!

Comment: @Zahir Your welcome :) please consider accept best answer to help people understand question has been solved if solution worked for Your question

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you do it.  Please let me know if you need anything more.

View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index59</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var userInterfaceGroups;//undefined at first
            $("#btn").click(function (ev) {

                var select = $("#SeTime option:selected").val();
                alert(select);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Home/PostTime",
                    data: { 'selectedtTime': select },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                    },
                    error: function (Result) {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });

            })
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    @Html.DropDownList("SeTime", new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem{ Text="1 Min", Value = "60" },
        new SelectListItem{ Text="2 Min", Value = "120" },
        new SelectListItem{ Text="3 Min", Value = "180" },
    }, "Select Time")
    @*ajax is a button click not a submit*@
    <input type="button" value="Set Time" id="btn" />
</body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PostTime(string selectedtTime )
    {
        //put a checkpoint here and interrogate selectedTime and work with it
        return Json(new
        {
            aValue = "aValueRet"
        }
               , @"application/json");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use url: `'@Url.Action("Details","Home")' + "/" + select` to send select parameter to controller. I added .Netfiddle. It works [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ar6VHd)

```
public ActionResult Details(string selectedtTime)
{
    var time = selectedtTime;
    return Json(new { data = time}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

$(function () {
    $('#myForm').submit(function () {
      var select = $("#SeTime option:selected").val();
      $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Details","Home")' + "/" + select,
        type: this.method,
        data: {'selectedtTime' : select},
        success: function(result) {
          alert("Selected value: " + result.data);
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I am sorry, but it seems you are printing the value by "$("h1").html(select);" not from the controller to view..pls. correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Zahir I have updated again. at this time that parse data which comes from controller. this fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ar6VHd

Comment: @Zahir "result.data" comes from controller

Answer (score 0):

Change the following:

```
var select = $("#SeTime option:selected").val();
```

to:

```
var select = $("#SetTime option:selected").val();
```

Also change:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SeTime", new List<SelectListItem>
```

to:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SetTime", new List<SelectListItem>
```

Comment: Sorry, but what changes you are suggesting as both seems same to me. thanks

Comment: You were missing a "t" in Se**t**Time for both instances.